# For $R=\mathbb{Z}[x]/ (x^2+5)$, find an ideal $I$ of $R$ which is not principal.

Tags: ring-theory, ideals, principal-ideal-domains

Can you check if it is correct? My approach is as follows:

$R=\mathbb{Z}[x]/ (x^2+5)$ is isomorphic to $\{ax+b|a,b\in\mathbb{Z}\}$. We can consider two types of ideals in $R$. For $m\in\mathbb{Z}$ an ideal $(m)$ in R is $\{ax+b|a,b\in\mathbb{mZ}\}$. For $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, an ideal $(nx)$ is $\{cx+d|c\in\mathbb{nZ},d\in\mathbb{5nZ}\}$. Let $gcd(m,n)=i$ and $gcd(m,5n)=j$. Then, an ideal $(m,nx)$ in $R$ is $\{\alpha x+\beta|\alpha\in\mathbb{iZ},\beta\in\mathbb{jZ}\}$. However, the ideal $(m,nx)$ in $R$ can be expressed by one of two types of principal ideals.

I could not see where I was wrong. Can you help me?

Comment: The ideal class group of $\mathbb{Z}[w], w = \sqrt{-5}$ has two elements : $(1)$ and $(2,1+w)$

Comment: @user1952009 This seems to be a rather basic question in ring theory: I don't think the OP has yet studied ideal class groups and stuff.

Comment: @DonAntonio Yes I know, I gave him the solution as an hint.

Comment: Can you explain it further..? And, also can you correct where I was wrong?

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}[w]$ is the same ring as $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2+5)$ so simply translate what I wrote, and show this ideal is not principal. The ideal class group $J$ (of a Dedekind domain..) is the set of ideals such that every ideal can be written as $\frac{a}{b} C_j$ for some $a ,b\in R$ and $C_j \in J$.

Comment: Note we have $|a+bw|^2 = a^2+5b^2$ so if $a+bw | c+dw$ then $a^2+b^2 | c^2+d^2$. Thus, what are the elements dividing $2$ and $1+w$ ? From this, assume that $(2,1+w)$ is principal and find a contradiction.